# File completion colors for zsh

Tags: colors, zsh, tab-completion

When I use Tab to complete a filename and more than one file matches, zsh uses an unsuitable color. Consider the following screenshot which exemplifies the problem:

[image: zsh tab completion]

I have entered `vi .zsh` and pressed `Tab`.

How can I change this color?

These are the relevant parts of the .zshrc file:

```
setopt EXTENDED_GLOB
setopt NO_CORRECT
setopt COMPLETE_IN_WORD

autoload -U colors && colors

## Completions
autoload -U compinit
compinit -C

## case-insensitive (all), partial-word and then substring completion
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'

setopt prompt_subst
PROMPT='%{$fg[blue]%}%1.${vcs_info_msg_0_}%{$reset_color%} $ '
```

Comment: That's not from the default setup. So you'll need to say how you configured zsh.

Comment: @peth I want to change the color of the line reading `vi .zsh`. It starts out dark gray (like the completions below), upon pressing `Tab`, it changes the color to the light one shown in the screenshot.

Comment: @NickolayKolev I cannot reproduce this with the config you posted. Are you sure you aren't also using something like `zsh-syntax-highlighting`?